# Triggher method call on updating a field value

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, primeng, angular2-changedetection

I'm having fun with Angular Forms and primeNG.
I have a form with 2 `p-dropdown`: when i select a value from the first dropdown (the report Type) I have to update the values of the second one since they depend from the choice of the first one (display the values connected to the report Type).

In particular I need to trigger the `getFilteredReports()` method when the value of `selectedReportType` is updated (from the first dropdown indeed).

In the first dropdown I've used the `ngOnChanges` since I had the same problem and the initial reports are coming from an `@Input()`.

Here's the relevant code for the second case:

```
selectedReportType: ReportType = { label: '' };

  getFilteredReports() {
    return this.currentReportSubset = this.reportTypeAndSubset.get(this.selectedReportType?.label) ?? [];
  }
```

At the moment in my template I have the second dropdown with this line that retrieves the values

```
<p-dropdown
....
    [options]="getFilteredReports()"
....
</p-dropdown>
```

I absolutely want to avoid methods calls in the template since it's a bad practice and I'm using the CD On Push if this can be of any help.

If, of any help, that's the code of the first dropdown:

```
 <p-dropdown
      [options]="reportTypes"
      optionLabel="label"
      [filter]="true"
      filterBy="label"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedReportType"
      name="pickedReportType"
    >
      <ng-template let-selectedReport pTemplate="selectedItem">
        <div *ngIf="selectedReport">
          <div>{{ selectedReport.label }}</div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template let-report pTemplate="item">
        <div>
          <div>{{ report.label }}</div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-dropdown>
```

What is a clean way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `getFilteredReports` method when the first dropdown's value changes and then provide currentReportSubset to the second dropdown, like this:

In your ts file:

```
selectedReportType: ReportType = { label: '' };

getFilteredReports() {
    this.filteredReports = this.reportTypeAndSubset.get(this.selectedReportType?.label) ?? [];
}
```

In your html file:

```
<!-- First dropdown -->
<p-dropdown
    [options]="reportTypes"
    optionLabel="label"
    [filter]="true"
    filterBy="label"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedReportType"
    name="pickedReportType"
    (onChange)="getFilteredReports()"
>
  <ng-template let-selectedReport pTemplate="selectedItem">
    <div *ngIf="selectedReport">
      <div>{{ selectedReport.label }}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-report pTemplate="item">
    <div>
      <div>{{ report.label }}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>


<!-- Second dropdown -->
<p-dropdown
....
    [options]="filteredReports"
....
</p-dropdown>
```

In case it doesn't work right away, you're probably calling the `getFilteredReports` method asynchronously so you'll also need to let the change detector know it needs to do its thing:

```
getFilteredReports() {
    this.filteredReports = this.reportTypeAndSubset.get(this.selectedReportType?.label) ?? [];
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, what you typed is the result I'd like to obtain but the point is:
how can I call the getFilteredReports method when the first dropdown's value changes?

Comment: I added the call to `getFilteredReports()` in the `onChange` event of the first dropdown.

Comment: Hi Shai, It could work but I have to avoid calling methods in the template because as I said it's not a good practice and I would have the initial problem :(

Comment: The bad practice is to call a method in an input of a component. It's perfectly fine to call a function in an output of a component. This will call the function only when the event is fired. In short, `[someInput]=functionCall()` is bad, `(someEvent)=functionCall()` is fine. :)